# How to cite raw data shared by a client?

Tags: citations, data

My capstone student project is a consultation report. How do I cite a raw data sample (extracted from Google AdWords) shared directly by my client? No preference between APA and MLA, it's my only source for the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar situation (supercomputer benchmarks that never appeared in a complete form in print), I cited the guy who was so kind to share them to me as:

> Yon Tihiy, in a private communication. 2018

Obviously, you guess that above was not his real name.